# How to add an ID onto a created element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My original question was marked falsely by another user as a duplicate but the link provided did not answer any parts of the question asked so I will ask another. Making the site builder I ran into an issue where the prompt value when pressing okay is not used as the text in the created `h1`. Why is this? The class applies and creates all the elements I wanted to but the text is not present on the site at all, and there are no errors in the code because it all works fine.

```css
.new-hd {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.new-para {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.classic-hd {
  max-width: 100vw;
  width: 100vw;
  max-height: 15vh;
  height: 15vh;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#classic-hd-txt {
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-indent: 3vw;
}

.fa-times {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.25vh;
  right: 1vw;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Make a Site</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" class="new-hd">
    Make Header
    </button>
  <button type="button" class="new-para">
    Make Paragraph
    </button>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".new-hd").click(function() {
        var newHdTxt = window.prompt("What would you like your Header Text to be?", "Enter Response Here");
        var newHdCont = document.createElement("header");
        var newHd = document.createElement("h1");
        $(newHdCont).addClass("classic-hd");
        $(newHd).addClass("classic-hd-txt");
        document.getElementsByClassName("classic-hd-txt").innerHTML = newHdTxt;
        document.body.appendChild(newHdCont);
        newHdCont.appendChild(newHd);
        //alert(newTxt);
      });
      $(".new-para").click(function() {
        document.createElement("p");
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As the name says `document .getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`, meaning a list of elements, instead of an individual element. You probably want to do `newHd.innerText = newHdTxt` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and let you know how that goes.

Comment: Thank you again, that worked flawlessly! Now all I have to sort out is applying the style.

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question?

Comment: You shouldnt really be targeting this element by class, since class is not unique, this will target all elements with this class. Plus since you just created the element, you already have it in a variable, no need to search the DOM again.

Comment: @Pete The question in the title isn't very accurate because the real one is not able to be used seeing as I made one under the title already. Also Nik answered the question because his comment/ fix worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

On behalf of Nik who gave the answer, here is the way you resolve this. Instead of using the DOM selector `get.ElementsByClassName().innerHTML` use the method `newHd.innerText = newHdTxt`.

Answer (score -3):

use attr function to add id attribute.like this

```
$jqueryElement.attr('id', 'change_it_to_what_you_want_but_should_be_unique');
```

Comment: This solution is not nearly as clean as Nik's comment on the question. His fix works well and makes sense to me just by reading the syntax.

Comment: @JordanDunton you should post that as an answer if they don't within a reasonable amount of time.